# Delete .pdf files only if .xlsx files in directory have same filename?

Tags: bash, shell, files, directory, rm

I have folders with hundreds of `pdf` and `xls(x)` files that were mass exported from legal e-discovery systems. The filenames in these exports correspond to bates # such as `ABCD_00000001.pdf`, `ABCD_00000002.pdf`, ... , `ABCD_00002000.pdf`. These mass exports include a blank `pdf` file for *every single* `xls(x)` file - with both having the exact same filename. E.g., `ABCD_00000005.xlsx` is the xlsx file that was produced in the ediscovery system and `ABCD_00000005.pdf` is an extraneous blank pdf file that was created in the mass export.

These extraneous .pdf files probably result from a user error on the part of the people running these mass exports, but I don't usually have control over that side of the process. So I wanted to know if any relatively straightforward way to delete these extraneous .pdf without forcing someone to go through them manually.

Comment: Are they `.xls` or `.xlsx`?  Or could they be either?  Why can't you just delete all pdf files in that directory? Are there some pdf files you would like to save?

Answer (score 6):

Loop over the pdf files, use parameter expansion to extract the basename:

```
#!/bin/bash
for pdf in *.pdf ; do
    basename=${pdf%.pdf}
    if [[ -f $basename.xls || -f $basename.xlsx ]] ; then
        rm "$pdf"
    fi
done
```

*Update:* I got the logic backwards, should be fixed now.

Comment: Added slightly more efficient alternative.  If this folder is extensive, it could make a difference in processing time.

Comment: @Xalorous: But your "alternative" removed the files my solution tried to keep.

Comment: It's possible that I pasted the wrong one.  I'll post a separate answer with the more efficient version.

Comment: I agree with your decision to reject the suggested edit — new answers should be posted as new answers, not edits.  But I believe that Xalorous got it right and you (choroba) got it backwards.  If `ABCD_0000005.xlsx` and `ABCD_0000005.pdf` both exist, your code leaves `ABCD_0000005.pdf` alone.  But if `important.pdf` exists, and there’s no corresponding spreadsheet, your code deletes `important.pdf`.

Comment: Actually, I missed that his logic is inverted.  Taking out the ! would fix it though.  The real question is what if there's a pdf without matching xls(x).  What does OP want to happen then?  If they want them gone, then they need to just `rm -rf *.pdf`.  If not, then my answer.  Reading the question strictly, we're only to delete pdf files with matching xls(x) files.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I got it backwards. Silly me :-(

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the .xls(x) files and remove matching pdf files.

```
for xls in *.xls* ; do
    /bin/rm -f "${xls%.xls*}"".pdf"
done
```

If there's no matching pdf it won't hurt anything.

Comment: You don’t really need the `""`; i.e., you could do `/bin/rm -f "${xls%.xls*}.pdf"`.  But this looks like it should work.

Comment: I tried it both ways, the match failed without the "" in the middle.  Or maybe I made a different mistake at the same time.  I'm new to bash.